# How to subscribe a user to a youtube channel using an Android app?

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to create a Youtube based application and I can't find any information on how to subscribe the users to different channels.

Is it possible to do it? I can find information about how to do it using `php` but I'm wasting lots of time with no success trying to do it with `Android`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at the following content for accessing different Youtube channels?[image: createChannelIntent]. There are also sample Android apps showing how to use the Youtube API.

To locate the referenced method, use the original source link below. Make sure that you are clicking the YoutubeIntents class or try this direct [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#createChannelIntent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)). You can find the YoutubeAPI Player on the downloads [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) and sample applications may be found at this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications).

([original source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#Summary))

Comment: where did you find that method? in the source that you mention it doesn't appear.
Could you please tell me one of those sample projects?

Comment: I'm sorry Tommie, but I can't use that method. I can't find it in the official doc.

Comment: And again @TommieC. I've installed the demo app and I've went to the links you provided but there is no clue that tells that it is possible. Are you really really really sure that this is possible? If you are not sure, please don't tell information that you don't know for sure.

Comment: I agree with @JFValdes, I can't make it work neither

Answer (score 0):

Below code will open channel in youtube app.

```
private  void openChannel(){
  String channelId = "";// put channel id
  Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createChannelIntent(getContext(),channelId);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```